# Access denied, VKApi, groups.getRequests

Tags: api, vk

I get a token through Implicit Flow

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&scope=327680&response_type=token
```

Standalone application.

Trying to fulfill the request groups.getRequests

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getRequests?group_id={groupId}&access_token={accessToken}
```

I get the answer:

```
{"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"groups.getRequests"},{"key":"group_id","value":"xxx"}]}}
```

Through the form at the bottom of the https://vk.com/dev/groups.getRequests page, the request is successfully executed on the same group.

Other requests groups. * (Except for groups.approveRequest) are executed without problems. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your access token has the [**groups** permission](https://vk.com/dev/permissions) when generated. If you generate it from another user, make sure they have administrator permissions in the group.

Answer (score 0):

https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=1914441&client_secret=***&= https://vk.com/id95207078***&password=***&v=5.103&2fa_supported=1